# Using parameter array in Azure Automation Powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, parameters, azure-automation

For a function I want to use an array of `DayOfWeek` to exclude certain days from the automation script. For that I've setup the following function:

```
Param
(
    [Parameter (Mandatory= $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [DayofWeek[]] $ExcludeDays
)

foreach ($ExcludeDay in $ExcludeDays)
{
    Write-Output $ExcludeDay
}
```

In the Azure testpane I've included the array as follows:

[image: Input example]

and this is the error it returns:

```
Failed
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'ExcludeDays'. Cannot convert value "Monday, Friday, Saturday" to type "System.DayOfWeek[]".
```

I've tried it simularly in Powershell by creating a function that takes the same parameter array and had no issue with similar input. Anybody knows how to get it working?

Comment: I reckon that's because what's being passed in is actually a `[string]`. You should change your parameter definition to match the incoming type and then perform the parsing/conversion in the body of your function e.g. `$ExcludeDaysString -split ","`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass them as `['Monday','Friday','Saturday']`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should pass them as `['Monday','Friday','Saturday']`. as Joy answered

another solution would be get input as
Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday

and split it.

$CharArray = $InputString.Split(",")